# CentOS 6 Transation Check Error - Updating fails

Tags: centos, cpanel

I am having an issue updating my server OS. Here is the list of errors I get when I run `sudo yum update`:

```
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/package.json from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-which-1.0.5-8.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/bin/which from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-which-1.0.5-8.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-which-1.0.5-8.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/package.json from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-uid-number-0.0.3-7.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/get-uid-gid.js from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-uid-number-0.0.3-7.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-uid-number-0.0.3-7.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/package.json from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-osenv-0.0.3-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-osenv-0.0.3-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp from install of nodejs-2:8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp from install of nodejs-
```

**The list is much longer!**

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the partial list that you have installed a version of `nodejs` (`8.17.0` with `nodesource` in the release string) that conflicts with the version provided by the system repositories (with `el6` in the release string).
Now when you update, either some system remnant is trying to update, or the system repository provides an update that satisfies the version requirement to update the package you've installed, but there are conflicts because of differences in how they are packaged or in the dependencies of the system package.

It *might* be sufficient to tell `yum` to skip updating `npm` (as this is at least one clear conflict in the list of outputs you've shown and it may be responsible for pulling in the other conflicting updates)

```
sudo yum update --exclude=npm
```

If you only want to keep the newer `nodejs` version, you should look for all traces of `nodejs`/`npm` packages coming from the system repositories (they will likely have `el6` in the package release string) and `yum remove` them, so that the updated version is the *only* version remaining.
However, while doing this you may find other packages that require the old version, and you should not force this without considering the potential impact on your system.